# Having this error "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/task/frontend/build/index.html" while deploying to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, mern, vercel

Recently, I created this MERN Stack Ecommerce website and I am having trouble deploying it to Vercel.
Here's my repo: https://github.com/rahulgore7/Ecommerce

Error in backend

```
{"success":false,"message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/task/frontend/build/index.html'"}
```

Error in frontend: Its showing a blank screen and not loading at all.
Both the frontend and backend have been deployed separately under client and server structure.

For backend I think I am getting error in my app.js file:

**Here's my backend/app.js**:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const path = require("path");

const errorMiddleware = require("./middleware/error");

// Config
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "PRODUCTION") {
  require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config/config.env" });
}

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(fileUpload());

// Route Imports
const product = require("./routes/productRoute");
const user = require("./routes/userRoute");
const order = require("./routes/orderRoute");
const payment = require("./routes/paymentRoute");

app.use("/api/v1", product);
app.use("/api/v1", user);
app.use("/api/v1", order);
app.use("/api/v1", payment);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

// Middleware for Errors
app.use(errorMiddleware);

module.exports = app;
```

**backend/server.js:**

```
const app = require("./app");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");
const connectDatabase = require("./config/database");

// Handling Uncaught Exception
process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
  console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
  console.log(`Shutting down the server due to Uncaught Exception`);
  process.exit(1);
});

// Config
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "PRODUCTION") {
  require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config/config.env" });
}

// Connecting to database
connectDatabase();

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is working on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});

// Unhandled Promise Rejection
process.on("unhandledRejection", (err) => {
  console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
  console.log(`Shutting down the server due to Unhandled Promise Rejection`);

  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

**backend/vercel.json:**

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "native-server",
    "builds": [{ "src": "server.js", "use": "@vercel/node" }],
    "routes": [{ "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/server.js" }]
  }
```

**backend/package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.26.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.5",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.3",
    "stripe": "^8.174.0",
    "validator": "^13.6.0"
  }
}
```

**Here's the frontend files:
frontend/package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.17.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.5.1",
    "country-state-city": "^3.0.1",
    "overlay-navbar": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.3",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }, 
  "proxy": "http://192.168.56.1:4000"
}
```

```
I have tried changing the package.json and proxy setting multiple times. But nothing happend.Hers's the build log from Vercel for the backend deployment:

[12:53:49.024] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[12:53:49.407] Cloning github.com/rahulgore7/Ecommerce (Branch: master, Commit: 487d24c)
[12:53:49.866] Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
[12:53:50.126] Cloning completed: 718.913ms
[12:53:50.389] Running "vercel build"
[12:53:50.887] Vercel CLI 33.0.1
[12:53:51.040] WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
[12:53:51.687] Installing dependencies...
[12:53:54.699] npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.6.5: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
[12:53:54.815] 
[12:53:54.816] added 108 packages in 3s
[12:53:54.816] 
[12:53:54.817] 3 packages are looking for funding
[12:53:54.817]   run `npm fund` for details
[12:53:59.045] Build Completed in /vercel/output [7s]
[12:53:59.353] Deploying outputs...
[12:54:03.503] 
[12:54:03.749] Deployment completed
[12:54:05.711] Uploading build cache [4.20 MB]...
[12:54:06.549] Build cache uploaded: 837.617ms
```